# Efficient tool for making tree-like shapes

Tags: modeling

DISCLAIMER: I am quite new, so this might seem like a stupid question.

PROBLEM: I'm trying to model this tree I found some pictures off.
I'm doing the branches like this but it is quite tedious. (I can't insert a video?)
Basically making a cylinder, loop cutting it, and dragging, resizing, rotating, them to fit over the reference image.
Here is pictures of process:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

QUESTION: Is there a more efficient way of doing this? A tool I can use that bends meshes easier without having to mess with the vertices in edit mode?

Comment: Have you had a look at the shipped [Sapling](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/add_curve/sapling.html) add-on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Skin Modifier

- add a new mesh object, go to edit mode, delete all vertices
- add **Skin modifier**
- in edit mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> mouse click create a new vertex
- now you can start draw branch by another click with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or press <kbd>E</kbd> (extrude)
- change thickness of vertex by <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on mac (Ctrl+A on pc?)

[image: ---]

**Notes**: you can change size (thickness) also

- from *3Dview > Properties panel (N) > Vertex Data > Radius X/Y*
- or check or reasign shortcut in *User Pref >  Keymap* > search **Skin Resize**

---

### Grease Pencil

You can use **Annotation** or **Grease Pencil** object to draw branch and convert to mesh and use *Skin* modifier. But it is probably more work. Like with *Annotate* tool ** you will have to *Convert to GP*, than *Convert GP to Curve*, than *Convert to Mesh*. Using default *Annotate* tool generates smooth but vertex intensive line that doesn't fits to *Skin* modifier later (you would have to use *Simplify* add-on in step *Convert GP to Curve* ...